# JavaScript: checking for null and undefined

Tags: javascript

This question has been answered earlier. I checked multiple question in SO but i am not able to understand that properly. Apologies for that.

I am using ajax and data is coming from database.

```
if(data.count > 0 ){
    $.each(data.content, function(key, value ){
if((value.technology) != ''){
 html+='<button class="form-control" disabled>'+value.technology+'</button>&nbsp;';
                            }
```

i also tried this

```
if((value.technology6 !== 'null')){
     alert(value.technology6);
  html+='<button class="testsss testss" disabled>'+value.technology6+'</button>&nbsp;';
                            }
```

and tried this as well

```
if(!(value.technology7)){
 html+='<button class="testsss testss" disabled>'+value.technology7+'</button>&nbsp;';
  }
```

problem is i am getting null as output. i am not sure what am i doing wrong and what is the proper way to check null and undefined.

Thanks for your advise.

Comment: Have you tried logging `value` in your loop? What does `data.content` look like?

Comment: `if (value.technology)` will skip both, but it will also skip `false`, `NaN`, `0` and `''` so it depends on what you want to do with those

Comment: are you getting any logs in console?

Comment: do you want `if((value.technology7)){`  instead of `if(!(value.technology7)){`  no "!"

Comment: Could you post a segment of the data from the server?

Comment: `null` is a null-value `'null'` is a String containing the word "null". `null !== 'null'`. Fix your condition!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check Undefined**

```
if(x != undefined)
{
    //x is defined
} else {
    //x is not defined
}
```

**Check Null**

```
if(y != null)
{
    //y is not null, we can do stuff
} else {
    //uh-oh, y is null
}
```

Also:

```
z = null;
w = undefined;
console.log(z == w); //Returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

please check if value and data are not null or undefined , then write them in alert() function to see what alert you are getting like alert(data.content); or alert(value) ..

else check of null is correct. to check undefined you have to check like

```
if(data.content != undefined){
// your code here 
}
```

if you can more elaborate what is in there data and value , might help to solve your problem more appropriately